# the meaning of that is statements?

Tags: american-english, learning

I see the word that used in different context with different meanings, yesterday is just saw a statement says:
"What's the worst thing that could happen?"
and I was wondering what is the difference from
"What's the worst thing could happen?"

what I want to know is what the value that comes with the word "That" in the first one.

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question is grammatical.

**that** is a conjunction that joins the first part of the sentence **What's the worst thing** with the second **could happen**.

Your second question is not grammatical.

People might speak like that in conversation but the use of **that** is understood.

You could omit **that** if you turn your question into a statement:

> In those circumstances the worst (possible) thing could happen.

http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-that/

Comment: thank you Ronald